# Store existing buttons in a array in c#

Tags: c#

so far I Have this code.

```
Button[] buttons = this.Controls
  .OfType<Button>()
  .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    buttons[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    buttons[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

and it gives me a `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I have 25 buttons.

Comment: Why not `i < buttons.Length` in case you change the number of buttons?

Comment: Are you sure? why don't you do this: `for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)`?

Comment: What is `this`?  Is it a form?  Also, are any of your buttons inside other containers like a `Panel` or `GroupBox`?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check the size of the button array?

Comment: You should use `foreach` to safely loop through them or `button.Length`.
And learn debugging skills)

Comment: My favorite button is `F9`. Use it to set a breakpoint in your code, so you can hover the mouse over `buttons`  and `i` and see what the problem is.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway it's inside a group box

Comment: Then you should be doing something like :`Button[] buttons = this.groupbox1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();`

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Thanks for the tip, I have been manually clicking with the mouse each time I needed a break point.  <3

Comment: You need a recursive function to run through all the controls in the form, returning your arrary of buttons. All container controls have its own Controls collection.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use *magic numbers* (`25`):

```
Button[] buttons = this.Controls
  .OfType<Button>()
  .ToArray();

foreach (var button in buttons) {
  button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  button.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

If you insist on `for` loop (please, notice `buttons.Length` - *actual* array's length):

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++) {
  buttons[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  buttons[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a groupbox container.. having a large difference?

Comment: @Frank gagui: no, probably you'll want to change the *Linq* a bit (say, get not all the buttons but within the groupbox only)

Answer (score 2):

Using the Length of the array in the for loop statement should prevent the out of range exception.

```
  Button[] buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
  {
     buttons[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
     buttons[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
  }
```